# Как разделить переменную из цикла на другую переменную?

Tags: php, mysql, for

В php новичок, как можно разделить i-тую переменную из цикла на другую переменную?
В моем случае $row[2] на $h. Т.е. если значение $row = 600, то после деления выведет 10.

```
require_once 'conf.php';
$h = 60;
$query ="SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 3";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
if($result)
{
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<table><tr><th>Id</th><th>Time</th></tr>";
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 1 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 1 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаток PHP, но разве `$row[2] / $h` не сработает?

Comment: `for ($j = 0 ; $j < 1 ; ++$j)`  - интересный аналог `if (true)`

Comment: я пытался так сделать, но в таком случае никаких вычислений не происходит, все выводится как текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, вы смешиваете интерполяцию строк с вычислением выражения.

Можно использовать конкатенацию:

```
echo "<td>".($row[2]/$h)."</td>";
```

Comment: спасибо, действительно, все сработало